# JavaScript splitting a value into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a rating system, which rounds values to the nearest 0.5 and contains values between 0 and 5.

How can I iterate over an array, splitting a value (rounded to nearest 0.5), into units.

`let rating = 3.7`

`let adjustedRating = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2);`

e.g. 3.7: `['1','1','1','1',0]`

1.4 would equal `['1', '0.5', '0', '0', '0']`

`let starsToShow = new Array().fill('0');
 starsToShow.forEach((v, i) => {
   ...
 });`

Comment: why `1.4 would equal ['1', '0.5', '0', '0', '0']` 1.4 should equal to that ?

Comment: I'm rounding the rating up to the nearest half value.

Comment: @PranavCBalan it would return as 2, ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0']

Comment: @rickysullivan then `3.7` should be `['1','1','1','1',0]` ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan, whoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it using **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**

```js
let rating = 3.7
let adjustedRating = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2);

console.log(
  Array.from({
    // set array length here
    length: 5
  }, function(_, i) { // iterate over element to update
    // get the difference with index
    var dif = adjustedRating - i;
    // based on the difference assign the array value
    return dif >= 1 ? '1' : dif > 0 ? '0.5' : '0';
  })
);
```

---

With simple for loop

```js
var rating = 3.7,
  res = [],
  adjustedRating = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var dif = adjustedRating - i;
  res.push(dif >= 1 ? '1' : dif > 0 ? '0.5' : '0');
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Cool solution. I didn't know about `Array.from`. Much less code than the one I suggested.

Comment: Nice, and using ES 2015 :)

Comment: ```var dif = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2) - i;```

Answer (score 1):

Just another entry, using *reduce* and *forEach*. *from* is probably better if less code matters (1 line?), but compatibility may be an issue.

```js
// Using forEach
function getRating0(rating) {
  var stars = [0,0,0,0,0];
  rating = Math.round(rating * 2) / 2;
  stars.forEach(function(v, i) {
    stars[i] = rating > 1? 1 : rating > 0? rating : 0;
    --rating;
  });
  return stars;
}  

// Using reduce
function getRating(rating) {
  var stars = [0,0,0,0,0];
  rating = Math.round(rating * 2) / 2;
  return stars.reduce(function(acc, v, i) {
    stars[i] = rating > 1? 1 : rating > 0? rating : 0;
    --rating;
    return stars;
  }, stars);
}  

console.log(getRating0(1.2));
console.log(getRating0(3.7));
console.log(getRating(1.2));
console.log(getRating(3.9));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.calculate-button').click(function(){
  var rating = $('.rating').val();
  var array = new Array();
  while (rating > 0){
    var currentRating;
    if(rating > 1)
    {
      var currentRating = 1;
      rating -= currentRating;
      array.push(currentRating);
    }
    else{
      var currentRating = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);
      rating = 0;
      array.push(parseFloat(currentRating));
  }
}

   while (array.length < 5)
   {
     array.push(0);
   }

  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="rating"/>
<button class="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work as you wanted to, but I would prefer if you would take the suggestion of AlienHoboken. It's much cleaner.

```
let rating = 3.7;
let adjustedRating = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2);

let tempRating = adjustedRating;
let starsToShow = new Array(5).fill(0);

for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  if (tempRating > 0.5) {
    tempRating -= 1.0;
    starsToShow[i] += 1.0;
  } else {
    starsToShow[i]+= 0.5;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(starsToShow);
```